# Keep state of variable PHP without querying

Tags: php, postgresql, state

I'm working on page with articles. We can vote on each article. I want to display all articles and above average voted articles on separate pages. My current scenario is something like this:

```
//For get all articles
GET ALL RECORDS FROM ARTICLES TABLE

//For above average articles
GET ALL RECORDS WITH VOTE ABOVE
    GET AVERAGE VOTE VALUE FROM ARTICLES TABLE
FROM ARTICLES TABLE
```

Which I find very inefficient. There are two events which changes average vote:

- Somebody voted on an article
- Somebody wrote an article

Is there any way I can track average vote value without querying database on every request? I guess I have to save state of how many votes has been sent and how many articles were written. Should I write those two vars in file, is this secure?

Comment: I would keep a sum and count in two separate columns as a denormalisation step; the average is trivial then.

Answer (score 1):

Just use your database as intended, it is as efficient as you're going to get. If you want to cut down on database traffic than use caching ([Choosing a PHP caching technique: output caching into files vs. opcode caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821978/choosing-a-php-caching-technique-output-caching-into-files-vs-opcode-caching)) don't re-architect something that works and add needless complexity.

PHP doesn't have static variables that are persistent between requests, this makes an obvious / simple solution to the problem (you don't really have a problem, but your perceived inefficiency) impossible. Serializing variables to a file and having to read that file every request is not the way to go, file system IO is the least efficient construct.